# Full screen fixed background image scroll reveal issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, z-index

I am having a slight issue with a full screen fixed background image on a page on my portfolio. On top of it are two divs, an introduction and a description, seperated by a gap - which reveals the background image.

To create the gap to reveal the image, I simply added a big margin to the bottom of the introduction div. On high resolution screens when the browser is full screen this looks perfect, however I have noticed that on lower resolution screens (or when the browser window is reduced in height) the background image doesn't seem to fill the full height of the window, as a lot of white space is added above the description div.

Any suggestions to stop this happening or if there is a better way of achieving this simple effect and ensuring its responsive would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you. It looks good for me in firebug but may not be what you are desiring;

```
#appBg {
    background: url("../images/app-banner2.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I would also suggest re taking the background image so that the hand holding the phone is more central.